# mariadb-server syntax error

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, mysql

I am writing a bash script and having trouble with `$PASSWORD`. Can anyone please tell me the correct way to write sql lines in bash script?

```
QUERY="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $PASSWORD;"
SQL="${QUERY1}"
mysql -uroot -p$PASSWORD -hlocalhost -e "$SQL"
```

I would appreciate if someone correct my approach rather suggesting another.

Comment: Never, in the code fragment you posted, do you assign a value to `PASSWORD`, so its value is probably `""`, and your command looks like `QUERY="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY ;" SQL="${QUERY1}" mysql -uroot -p -hlocalhost -e "$SQL"`, which will cause unhappiness.

Comment: Try `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY $PASSWORD WITH GRANT OPTION;` and i think there should be space between -u and root. so it would be `sudo mysql -u root -p $PASSWORD`

Comment: In your script did you specify PASSWORD variable?

Comment: Yeah I did like, PASSWORD='my pass', and I want to pass this value through $PASSWORD in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to quote the password in the query and you assigned non-existing `QUERY1` variable to `SQL`. This should work:

```
QUERY="GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON db.* TO 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '$PASSWORD';"
mysql -uroot -p$PASSWORD -hlocalhost -e "$QUERY"
```

Comment: I don't understand, what you want to say. [Command syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) requires single quotes around password string.